# Changing a Guid variable when user is admin

Tags: c#, razor

I'm building out a quick prototype app that has two hardcoded users with test data a patient user and an admin. New users can also be created but will not have any data to display they can only add. I have a situation where I call a method that takes in a Guid as a parameter. When the user is admin I want to pass in a hardcoded Guid for the pre existing patient user, When not admin I want to base it off the Guid attached to the user session, below is my razor code which is currently not working.

```
Guid patientID = new Guid("3aac8d07-ad35-e311-8bdf-9ebf7757768f");

@if(userSession.IsAdmin == "TRUE")
{
    System.Data.DataSet ds = MeasuredHealthBeta1.Utilities.DataHelper.Measurements_Get306060DayGlucoseMeasurements(patientID );
}
else
{
    System.Data.DataSet ds = MeasuredHealthBeta1.Utilities.DataHelper.Measurements_Get306060DayGlucoseMeasurements(userSession.UserIDNative);
}
```

The error "External component has thrown an exception" occurring is when the view containing this razor code goes to get loaded using the following method

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("../Metrics/ReportsHistoryList", Model, new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { { "MeasurementTypeGroupIDs", defaultMeasurementTypeIDs } });}
```

Comment: is userSession.UserIDNative is GUID type?

Comment: What's the exception the external component threw?

Comment: yes, it is of Guid type

Comment: To be honest I don't actually understand what the exception actually means.

Comment: How can I view the exception of that external component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was getting was actually that `DataSet ds` was being used outside the scope of the if statement. To fix this rather than wrapping the method call with the condition, I wrapped the Guid I was trying to pass in instead. Here was the code I used that ended up working out for me, it's dirty/hackish and I most likely don't need that else in there either.

```
Guid patientID = userSession.UserIDNative;
if(userSession.IsAdmin.ToUpper() == "TRUE")
{
    patientID = new Guid("3aac8d07-ad35-e311-8bdf-9ebf7757768f");
}
else
{
    patientID = userSession.UserIDNative;
}

System.Data.DataSet ds = MeasuredHealthBeta1.Utilities.DataHelper.Measurements_Get306060DayGlucoseMeasurements(patientID);
```